# Angular 2 - display external page in a component

Tags: angular, http, typescript, angular-components

I'm new to Angular 2 and I wonder if it's possible to create a component which after loading would display external webpage like google calendar or anything else.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible? if yes, what should I look for? I haven't found any working answers on the internet. I tried to make an iFrame but it doesn't display anything due to
"Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'
"

Comment: You could use window.load

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward any documentation? nothing appears when I google it

Comment: sorry I meant window.location. So in your ngonit method: window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';

Comment: It doesn't work. And I'm not sure if you understand my issue. I want external website to be rendered/displayed inside of my module. For instance I have some kind of nav bar on the left and on main area of the screen I have angular2 component which is displaying google calendar

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this might help some people.

You can do this in your Angular component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  externalPage: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get('https://google.com/', { responseType: 'text' })
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.externalPage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(res);
      });
  }
}
```

Then in your HTML

```
<div [innerHtml]="externalPage"></div>
```

However for it to work, your external site needs to have enabled CORS:

```
access-control-allow-methods: GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

Otherwise, you'll hit the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://google.com/' from origin 'https://display-external-html-into-angular-vqyiga.stackblitz.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```